# Google earth kmz opening in symbols and code in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I installed notepad++ via cnet installer on a standalone laptop, no internet connection. My kmz files from Google earth are opening in symbols and code. I set preferences to xml for language and added kmz to xml file extension configuration but still no luck. It's always worked on my system at work but I'm teleworking and really need to figure this out. Two of my kmz files won't import into my software so I need to be able to compare their xml to the ones that work.

Answer (score 1):

You may know form Google API docs:

> A KMZ file consists of a main KML file and zero or more supporting files that are packaged using a Zip utility into one unit, called an archive.
> Google Earth and Google Maps can read KML and KMZ files directly, and they can save files as KMZ files. By default, the main KML file is named doc.kml.

Notepad++ is a text editor. So because KMZ is a ZIP file format, it cannot be opened directly by Notepad++.

If you want to compare the extracted KML files in XML format, you have to install the **Compare** extension in Notepad++ from the main menu.

```
Plugins > Plugins Admin
```

Answer (score 1):

One simple solution to my problem that I have seems similar to yours. What I did was opening  the kmz files in google map, saving the files as kml from google earth itself. Then open in Notepad ++. Hope this helps.